# $this->post() Giving NULL strangely CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, rest

during testing I checked my one specific function doesn't work like it should be and Here is my code and configurations before i give you facts:

**.htaccess:(root of codeIgniter)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**Tester Controller:**

```
class Tester extends REST_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        // Construct the parent class
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Tester_model');
        // Configure limits on our controller methods
        // Ensure you have created the 'limits' table and enabled 'limits' within application/config/rest.php
        $this->methods['user_get']['limit'] = 50000; // 500 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['user_post']['limit'] = 10000; // 100 requests per hour per user/key
        $this->methods['user_delete']['limit'] = 5000; // 50 requests per hour per user/key
    }

    public function courseinfo_post(){

    $cc = $this->post('courseid'); // test it like coursed = 7

    if($cc == ""){
        $this->response([
                        'status' => FALSE,
                        'value' => $cc
                    ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }else{
        $this->set_response([ ‘status’ => TRUE ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
   }

   public function test_post(){
    $dd = $this->post('hi'); // test it like hi=7
    $this->response([
            'value1' => $dd
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
 }
}
```

I gave it several trials and come to know following facts:

- Function `courseinfo_post()` with parameter `courseid=7` is not working rather it gives null why is that?
- Why same type of method `test_post()` is working absolutely fine with parameter `hi=7`.
- I have noticed if I pass more than one parameter in my function `courseinfo_post()` it work fine , why is that?

Note: I am working on codeIgniter is `3.0.6` defined in `system/core/CodeIgnitor`

How can I make `courseinfo_post()` work with only one parameter as it is?

Comment: sorry that was typo

Comment: use $this->input->post() instead of $this->post();

Comment: are you trying to retrive data from post method

Comment: yes exactly @RanjanaLK , but this simple task have made my day

Comment: @Kool-Mind doesn't work either

Comment: @Mr.Z Then it should be $this->input->post();

Comment: @Mr.Z but u should use $this->input->post('courseid')

Comment: not working `$this->input->post('courseid');` or `$this->input->post();`

Comment: @Mr.Z try `print_r($this->input->post());` to see post data

Comment: @Mr.Z if `'courseid'` doesn't exist in your post data you should definitely have a problem. what is your `print_r($this->input->post());` look like

Comment: @RanjanaLK output: `Array ( [courseid] => 7 ) {"status":true,"value":null}` , where value is actually variable `$cc`

Comment: @Mr.Z where did you declare `$coureId` variable before using it in `if($coureId == "")` ?

Comment: that's typo it was `$cc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121749/discussion-between-ranjanalk-and-mr-z).

Comment: Use `system/core/CodeIgniter` instead of `system/core/CodeIgnitor`

Answer (score 1):

please use correct syntax i.e  $this->input->post('courseid');

```
$cc = $this->input->post('courseid'); // test it like coursed = 7

instead of

$cc = $this->post('courseid'); // test it like coursed = 7
```

or try

```
print_r($this->input->post(null,TRUE));
```

or update your code whenever u use rest

```
 class my_controller_name extends REST_Controller{

         public $requestVar = array( 'courseid'=>'',
                                     );
         public function courseinfo_post(){
                $response =  $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
                $response = (is_array($response)?array_map("trim", $response):'');
                foreach($this->requestVar as $key=>$var){
                    $this->requestVar[$key] = urldecode((isset($response[$key])?$response[$key]:$this->requestVar[$key]));
                }

                print_r($this->requestVar); // use it wherever u need

         }

        }
```

Comment: print_r($this->input->post(null,TRUE));

Comment: it will give you all post values with keys. just print n let me know

Comment: this is result : `Array ( [cid] => 8 ) {"status":true,"value":null}` with 200:OK

Comment: yhea cid is there u got what u need, anything else u need

Comment: it's there but i can't use it notice `value` variable its null which is actually else part of my code , so it means it receives parameter value but doesn't assign it why is that

Comment: wait sharing u code updating the answer, use my way

Comment: you are added form helper in autoload.php file